# awk: gsub /pattern1/, but not /pattern1pattern2/

Tags: awk, gsub, substitution

In my work, I have to solve such a simple problem: change pattern1 to newpattern, but *only* if it is *not* followed by pattern2 *or* pattern3:

```
"pattern1 pattern1pattern2 pattern1pattern3 pattern1pattern4" → "newpattern pattern1pattern2 pattern1pattern3 newpatternpattern4"
```

Here is my solution, but I don't like it and I suppose there should be a more elegant and easy way to do that?

```
$ echo 'pattern1 pattern1pattern2 pattern1pattern3 pattern1pattern4' | awk '
{gsub(/pattern1pattern2/, "###", $0)
gsub(/pattern1pattern3/, "%%%", $0)
gsub(/pattern1/, "newpattern", $0)
gsub(/###/, "pattern1pattern2", $0)
gsub(/%%%/, "pattern1pattern3", $0)
print}'
newpattern pattern1pattern2 pattern1pattern3 newpatternpattern4
```

So, the sample input file:

```
pattern1 pattern1pattern2 aaa_pattern1pattern3 pattern1pattern4 pattern1pattern2pattern1
```

The sample output file should be:

```
newpattern pattern1pattern2 aaa_pattern1pattern3 newpatternpattern4 pattern1pattern2newpattern
```

Comment: could you please show us sample Input_file and expected sample output file too in code tags?

Comment: Is using awk a requirement? This would be trivial in perl.

Comment: @TomFenech Please post it anyway, the community will benefit from it later. This is a nice piece for lookahead.

Comment: @TomFenech Unfortunately I don't know perl (hope to learn it later), but anyway please post the solution in perl.

Comment: Never use the word `pattern` in the context of search and replace as it's ambiguous - use `string` or `regexp`, whichever it is you mean at each point. If you do that then you'll see that your example is a bad one. What you SHOULD be using instead is input that consists of strings and searching for regexps that match those strings (e.g. search for `fo+` not followed by `ba[rgh]` given input `foo foobar`) because when you do THAT then you realize you can't solve this with `gsub(/fo+ba[rgh]/,"###"); ... gsub(/###/,"fo+ba[rgh]")` as that would turn the string "foobar" into the string "fo+ba[rgh]"

Comment: Thanks, @EdMorton, that's very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is trivial in perl, using a negative lookahead:

```
perl -pe 's/pattern1(?!pattern[23])/newpattern/g' file
```

Substitute all matches of `pattern1` that are not followed by `pattern2` or `pattern3`.

If for some reason you need to do it in awk, then here's one way you could go about it:

```
{
    out = ""
    replacement = "newpattern"
    while (match($0, /pattern1/)) {
        if (substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH) ~ /^pattern[23]/) {
            out = out substr($0, 1, RSTART + RLENGTH - 1)
        }
        else {
            out = out substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1) replacement
        }
        $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    print out $0
}
```

Consume the input while `pattern1` matches and build the string `out`, inserting the replacement when the part after each match isn't `pattern2` or `pattern3`. Once there are no more matches, print the string that has been build so far, followed by whatever is left in the input.

Comment: Seems that's what I need! It really works. 

I wonder whether such a solution is possible with awk or I should urgently learn perl...

Comment: @EugeneBarsky:  AFAIK awk does not support look-ahead or look-behind, since it uses POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE)

Comment: You can do it with awk, by using `match` and taking substrings of the input line, but to be honest your requirement is a negative lookahead so you may as well use one.

Comment: @Tom Fenech, how should I write it in perl, if pattern1 and pattern2 in reality are totally different, e.g. ABCD and EFGH?

Comment: Use a standard regex OR inside the negative lookahead: `(?!(ABCD|EFGH))`.

Comment: @TomFenech, I was so impressed with the perl solution, that today began to read about this marvelous language.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky there's 2 things to read along with any other perl documentation: 1) http://www.zoitz.com/comics/perl_small.png and 2) https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html. They both make excellent points :-).

Comment: Fascinating, but ten years old, and shared by an awk evangelist. Awk's great but as you can see, perl gets the job done much more easily in this case. Despite what some people might tell you, there's no harm in using both tools!

Comment: Hardly an awk evangelist (I answer a lot of questions using sed, grep, shell, etc. as appropriate but many of the questions I look at just happen to need more text manipulation than those tools provide and so for those I provide awk answers) but since Eugene could see the positive of perl in terms of brevity for this case I thought it was reasonable for him to also be made aware of the negative in terms of code clarity and performance so he could make a balanced, well informed decision for himself on using it or not.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($0,flds,/pattern1(pattern2|pattern3)/,seps)
    for (i=1; i in flds; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", gensub(/pattern1/,"newpattern","g",flds[i]), seps[i]
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
newpattern pattern1pattern2 aaa_pattern1pattern3 newpatternpattern4 pattern1pattern2newpattern
```

With other awks you can do the same with a while(match()) loop:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/pattern1(pattern2|pattern3)/) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
        gsub(/pattern1/,"newpattern",tgt)
        printf "%s%s", tgt, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    gsub(/pattern1/,"newpattern",$0)
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
newpattern pattern1pattern2 aaa_pattern1pattern3 newpatternpattern4 pattern1pattern2newpattern
```

but obviously the gawk solution is simpler and more concise so, as always, get gawk!

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution. Nice question. Basically it's doing 2 gensubs:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){
    s=gensub(/pattern1/, "newpattern", "g", $i);
    t=gensub(/(newpattern)(pattern(2|3))/, "pattern1\\2", "g", s);
    $i=t
  }
}1
```

Testing:

```
 echo "pattern1 pattern1pattern2 aaa_pattern1pattern3 pattern1pattern4 pattern1pattern2pattern1" | awk -f tst.awk
 newpattern pattern1pattern2 aaa_pattern1pattern3 newpatternpattern4 pattern1pattern2newpattern
```

However, this will fail whenever you already have something like `newpatternpattern2` in your input. But that's not what OP suggests with his input examples, I guess.

Comment: Yes, it's almost a solution, but indeed it will fail on `newpatternpattern2`, so my solution in the post is more general.

Comment: Well, I provided you with a valid answer to your question. If you need a 'general' solution, next time, ask for one.

Comment: Of course you are right, thank you Marc.

I've learned that a 'general' solution is available only using lookahead, which is unavailable in awk.

Comment: No, you've learned that posting 1 line of sample input isn't adequate to explain your problem or provide something we can test a possible general solution against so many people are just not bothering to read your question. Lookaheads are syntactic sugar, you don't **need** them.